# Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///)

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I have a script that runs and downloads some data.
Everything works fine for around 60 pulls and then suddenly I get the error:

Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///)

```
while ( my $row = $ia_applicant_query->fetchrow_arrayref ) {

    s/\t/ /g for @$row;    # <------- THIS IS WHAT THE ERROR POINTS TO
    my $line = join "\t", map { defined $_ ? $_ : '.' } @$row;
    $mydb->func( "$line\n", "putline" );
}
```

The error is then just repeated for the remaining 800 pulls.
Any Idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: So what's @$row at that point in time?

Comment: Some of the columns probably contain NULL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That means one of the values in `@$row` is `undef`, which happens if the column is `NULL`.

This can be avoided by replacing

```
s/\t/ /g for @$row;
my $line = join "\t",  map { defined($_) ? $_ : '.' } @$row;
```

with

```
my $line = join "\t",  map { defined($_) ? s/\t/ /gr : '.' } @$row;   # 5.14+
```

or

```
sub tabs_to_spaces { ( my $s = shift ) =~ s/\t/ /g; $s }

my $line = join "\t",  map { defined($_) ? tabs_to_spaces($_) : '.' } @$row;
```